# jquery check if any element of collection / array has Class

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, if-statement

I'm trying to simplify a jquery code.
I have a selection of elements, and I want to check if ANY of those elements has a specific class, same specific class for all selectors.

```
if($(".sf-item-352").hasClass("sf-option-active") || $(".sf-item-356").hasClass("sf-option-active") || $(".sf-item-362").hasClass("sf-option-active")) {

     do_something();

} else {

     do_something_else();

}
```

the above code works perfectly, but I would like to use an array of selectors instead of having to write a condition for each selector (I might have to check a lot of selectors).

here's what I've been trying so far :

```
var elems = $(".sf-item-352, .sf-item-356", .sf-item-362");

elems.each(function() {

     if ($(this).hasClass("sf-option-active")) {

          do_something();

     } else {

          do_something_else();
     }

});
```

I obviously don't get the same results...
can somebody help me with this ? any advice ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an array of selectors you can combine them into a multi-part (comma-separated) query and then use `filter()` to see if any have the other class:

```
let selectors = ['.foo', '.bar', '.etc'];
if ($(selectors.join(', ')).filter('.someClass').length) {
    //some have the class
}
```

Comment: Why `.filter(...).length`?

Comment: @Andreas Because that filters the matched elements into a subset of elements that have the filter class, and `.length` is cast to truthy/falsy based on whether that subset contains 0 (false) or a non-zero number of elements (true).

Comment: [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com): _"Determine whether **any of the matched elements** are assigned the given class."_

Comment: Well sure, but my way works just fine too. With jQuery, as with life, there are often a million ways to achieve the same thing. Feel free to post up your own answer using `hasClass()`. I tend to prefer `filter().length` as it has wider application, not just for checking classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but you have some syntax errors. Here is a working code:

```js
const hasClass = $(".sf-item-352, .sf-item-356, .sf-item-362").hasClass("sf-option-active");
if (hasClass) {
  console.log("class exists");
} else {
  console.log("class does not exist");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sf-item-352">First div</div>
<div class="sf-item-356 sf-option-active">Second div</div>
<div class="sf-item-362">Third div</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
var elems = $(".sf-item-352, .sf-item-356", .sf-item-362");
```

into array of jQuery objects:

```
var elems = [$(".sf-item-352"), $(".sf-item-356"), $(".sf-item-362")];
```

Comment: Why three separate jQuery objects? And how does OP then check for the presence of the class?

Comment: I was correcting his code that wasn't working, where he said "here's what I've been trying so far"